# Ensuring selenium webdriver is correctly running

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Been using selenium for a couple years now and I have fortunately had little problems with it. Recently, I've had to develop a new app for which I've had to develop a "Web Driver Manager" script to handle updates of chrome etc. to ensure the webdriver is the correct version/etc. (Yes, I know that these already excist, but for reasons I rather not get into, I can't use webdriver_manager or similar packages).

My query is, when I launch a new driver `my_driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()` how extensive are the checks that selenium conducts with the driver? That is, I know it will output an error if the chromedriver.exe version is not compatiple with the installed Chrome version, or if the driver is corrupted. However, I am not sure how in-depth these tests go and how reliable they are. I.e. if selenium is just checking that your chromedriver.exe version matches one found within a list of acceptable versions for your installed Chrome. To me this would not be extensive enough of a test and I have to develop something in the background.

Is it possible that when I try to load a url `my_driver.get("some_url")`, or whatever, it will give me an error due to a selenium/driver error?

Many thanks in advance,

pb